# Objective-C: Share both, Text AND Image via UIDocumentInteractionController to Instagram/Facebook/Twitter

Tags: objective-c, facebook, share, instagram, uidocumentinteraction

I just want to know if there is a way to share a picture AND a text with the UIDocumentInteractionController.

I developed an app which has the functionality to share, and so far I can share pictures to facebook, twitter and instagram, but no text with the picture.

I am using the UIDocumentInteractionController because otherwise I couldn't manage to share pictures through instagram (for example it was not possible to do so with the ActivityViewController).

Comment: Have you had any luck with this? I'm trying to implement the same

Answer (score 0):

You can't, UIDocumentInteractionController is for documents. It is even in the name.

A solution would be to save the string to text file and share that file, or if you want to share a string, for example to post on a social network you should use UIActivityViewController

Comment: I don't know if there was a change since then, but the UIActivityViewController could not display for example Instagram. So this is no Solution, if I want to share on all(!) social networks.